# conventions for friend methods in Perl

Tags: coding-style, perl, conventions

Perl doesn't support a friend relationship between objects, nor does it support private or protected methods. What is usually done for private methods is to prefix the name with an underscore. I occasionally have methods that I think of as friend methods. Meaning that I expect them to be used by a specific object, or an object with a specific responsibility, but I'm not sure if I should make that method public (meaning `foo` ) or private ( `_foo` ) or if there's a better convention? is there a convention for friend methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any conventions or best practices for friend methods that the Perl community uses.  If you felt the need to designate a prefix for these methods I don't see any real issue with it, but I don't see any advantage in it either.  Personally I'd just make it a "public" method, without the underscore, and without any additional prefix.

Answer (score 4):

Perl does not, by itself, enforce private methods or attributes, no. In fact, Larry Wall was once [quoted](http://www.goodreads.com/author/quotes/89118.Larry_Wall) as saying:

> Perl doesn't have an infatuation with enforced privacy. It would
>   prefer that you stayed out of its living room because you weren't
>   invited, not because it has a shotgun.

If you're using [`Moose`](https://metacpan.org/module/Moose) (and if you aren't, you really, *really* should), you could put your method, which I'll call `foo`, into a [role](https://metacpan.org/module/Moose%3a%3aManual%3a%3aRoles), say `Fooable`, that can be composed into more than one class, thus allowing `foo` to be a method in any class that `does` the `Fooable` role.

If you want true privacy, though, it looks as though [`MooseX::Privacy`](https://m.metacpan.org/module/MooseX%3a%3aPrivacy) provides that, although I don't have any experience using it.

Comment: only problem I have with the role's suggestion is that a role becomes a part of the object, and that would ultimately seriously violate the single responsibility principle in any case where I'm thinking about friend methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to have *Friend* semantics you could do something like this:

```
package A;

use Data::Dumper;

sub _friend
{
   die "you are no friend of mine" unless caller(0)->isa(__PACKAGE__);
   my $self = shift;
   "friend";
}

package B;

use base 'A';

sub new
{
   bless {}, shift;
}

sub test_friend
{
shift->_friend;
}

package main;

$bob = new B;

print $bob->test_friend, "\n";

print $bob->_friend, "\n";
```

I named the method with an underscore so that Test::Pod will will not complain that it is not documented.